# Using blittable types in C++ / C# project without marshaling?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, byte, marshalling

I have a project that uses C++ and C#. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of blittable types. From my understanding, using blittable types means you don't have to perform any conversion when passing data between C++ and C#, i.e. you don't have to use the interop marshaler. Am I understanding this correctly?

I'm asking because I'm trying to pass data from a C++ function to C# **without** performing any conversion. I've been able to get the data back just fine using Marshal.Copy, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the data without using Marshal.Copy. If a blittable type (I'm using a byte), doesn't require conversion, then this should be possible right?

If it is possible, how do I go about doing this. My C++ function returns a byte* array as a type **void*** which.

On the C# side, I would like to take that byte array and save it instantly without any marshalling, e.g.

```
byte[] byteArray = FileAccessClass.GetByteArray();
/* GetByteArray is the C++ function */
```

Here is more of my code:

```
/* C# FileAccess.cs */
[DllImport("Test.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr getBytes(
    [In] string filePath,
    [In] string dataGroup); 

/* Header .h file. */
TEST_DLL void* getBytes(std::string filePath, std::string dataGroup);

/* Implementation C++ file. */
TEST_DLL void* getBytes(std::string filePath, std::string dataGroup)
{
    printf("getBytes entered."

    /* More code here...*/

    byte* byteArray = new byte[10];
    return byteArray;
}
```

My current implementation uses an IntPtr which is used with marshaling to convert to an int array. Is it possible to eliminate the marshaling step?

Comment: I don't think so. An array in .NET "knows" its length, but a C array is only a pointer. Btw. in your C sample code the function return not an array of byte but an array of byte pointers `new byte*[10]`.

Comment: That was a typo. My actual code has byte* data_out = new byte[10];. I've updated the post.